# Pessimistic locking in Activerecord - with_lock is not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to implement create_or_update method for `User` model, which will either create a new record or update the existing one.

```ruby
def create_or_update_user(external_user_id, data)
  user = User.find_or_initialize_by(external_user_id: external_user_id)
  user.title = data[:title].downcase
  # and so on - here we assign other attributes from data
  user.save! if user.changed?
end
```

The pitfall here is that this table is being updated concurrently by different processes and when they are trying to modify `user` with the same `external_user_id` then race condition happens and `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` is raised. I tried to use database lock to solve this problem, but it didn't work as expected - exception is still raised sometimes.

The table structure looks like this:

```ruby
create_table :users do |t|
    t.integer :external_user_id, index: { unique: true }
    # ...
end
```

updated method - what I'm doing wrong here?:

```ruby
def create_or_update_user(external_user_id, data)
  user = User.find_or_initialize_by(external_user_id: external_user_id)
  user.with_lock do
    user.title = data[:title].downcase
    # and so on - here we assign other attributes from data
    user.save! if user.changed?
  end
end
```

I can't use upsert, because I need model callbacks.

It probably can be fixed by adding

```ruby
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
  retry
end
```

but I want to use locks for best performance cause the race conditions is not a rare in this part of code.

UPD: added a gist to reproduce this race condition
https://gist.github.com/krelly/520a2397f64269f96489c643a7346d0f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, the error is likely still occurring in cases where two threads attempt to create a new User for an external id that doesn't exist.

In this situation, thread #1 would attempt to acquire a row lock on a row that does not exist - no locking would actually occur.

Thread #2 would be able to make the same find_or_initialize query while thread #1 is still building the record, and thus thread #2 would hit a uniqueness violation once it commits.

As you've already guessed, the only simple solution to this problem would be a rescue + retry. Thread #2 would just try again, and it would update the record created by thread #1.

An alternative solution would be an [advisory lock](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/advisory-locks-in-postgres) - a lock with application-specific behavior. In this case, you would be saying that only one thread at a time can run `create_or_update_user` with a specific external ID.

Rails doesn't support advisory locks natively, but the linked article contains an example of how you would do it with Postgres. There's also the gem [with_advisory_locks](https://github.com/ClosureTree/with_advisory_lock)